# Monkey patch ActiveAdmin class from engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, monkeypatching

I have an [engine](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) that will be installed over an application that uses [Active Admin](http://activeadmin.info/)...

After install Active Admin, I need to run my engine installer. This will create a file monkey patching an Active Admin class.

The file looks like this...

```
module ActiveAdmin
  module Devise
    # things I need to add...
  end
end
```

So, the question is: **where I need to put this file and why?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the [Railtie's](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Railtie.html) `initializer` method.

*my_engine/lib/admin_invitable/engine.rb*

```
module MyEngine
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace MyEngine
    initializer "ativeadmin_invitable_patch" do |app|
      require_relative "activeadmin_invitable_patch"
    end
  end
end
```

*my_engine/lib/admin_invitable/activeadmin_invitable_patch.rb*

```
module ActiveAdmin
  module Devise
    # bla bla
  end
end
```